# Emacs -- a non-C function for `vertical-motion` - - i.e., elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for an `elisp` function that is the equivalent of the one written in `C` for `vertical-motion`.

I would like to implement my own bug-fixes caused by `whitespace-mode` [`(setq whitespace-style '(face space-mark tab-mark newline-mark) )`] and `visual-line-mode` and perhaps some other contributing factors (e.g., `linum-mode` and `tabbar-mode`) -- e.g., when `point` is one *more* or one *less* than it should be; or when the last word in a line gets wrapped because the end of line is exactly equal to the `window-width` (and `vertical-motion` doesn't know the word has been wrapped).

It is still premature to file a bug report, so I thought I'd try to fix the function instead of creating several contingency plans as bug workarounds -- e.g., if `(vertical-motion 0)` should place `(point)`  at `(window-start)` but `(point)` ends up being one *more* than it should be, then pretend `(point)` is really one *less*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-motion` is a complex function.  Re-implementing it in Elisp would be difficult/impossible.  Better just report the problems you see as bugs.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll spend some additional time trying to come up with a recipe to recreate a few of the issues I'm seeing along with my workarounds -- I already have a few contingency plans that I've written.